# Python subprocess realtime output

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print in realtime the output from a C++ exe started from python 3.6.6-x64 using subprocess module. I tried everything from google and other questions and I always get the output when the subprocess exited.

This is the code snippet:

```
        try:
            process = Popen(fullcmdtokens, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, encoding='utf8', shell=True, errors='replace')
        except Exception as exception:
            print(exception)
        else:
            while process.poll() is None:
                for lline in process.stdout:
                    process.stdout.flush()
                    edit_and_do_stuff(lline)
                    print(lline)
```

I also tried using

```
process.stdout.readline()
```

and

```
process.stdout.read(1)
```

and i modified the C++ exe to flush after every print.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you don’t send stdout to a pipe:

```
try:
    process = Popen(fullcmdtokens, stderr=STDOUT, encoding='utf8', shell=True, errors='replace')
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception)
```

---

If you need to change each line:

```
try:
    process = Popen(fullcmdtokens, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, encoding='utf8', shell=True, errors='replace')
    while process.poll() is None:
        for lline in process.stdout:
            process.stdout.flush()
            edit_and_do_stuff(lline)
            print(lline)
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to be able to modifiy that output first. I will edit my question.

Comment: @tairqammar Updated.

Comment: I tried your example, but still doesn't work. Thanks anyway!